# How to send created tags back to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

Im using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) jquery plugin to add/create tags for posts on my ASP.NET MVC site. The features I use is "Loading Remote Data" and "Tagging Support" like this :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function tagResultList(tag) {
            var counter = 'ny tagg';

            var markup = "<table class='movie-result'><tr>";
            markup += "<td class='movie-info'><div class='movie-title'>" + tag.text

            if (typeof tag.count != 'undefined') {
                counter = tag.count;
            }

            markup += "(" + counter + ")</div>";
            markup += "</td></tr></table>"
            return markup;
        }

        function tagResultSelectionName(tag) {
            return tag.text;
        }


        $("#txtTagBox").select2({
            multiple: true,
            createSearchChoice:
                function (term, data) {
                    if ($(data).filter(function () { return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0; }).length === 0) {
                        return { id: 0, text: term };
                    }
                },
            placeholder: "Sök efter en tagg",
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            maximumInputLength: 30,
            maximumSelectionSize: 5,
            ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
                url: _tagsUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                quietMillis: 100,
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        q: term, // search term
                        page: page
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                    // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
                    return { results: data.Tags, more: data.MorePages };
                }
            },
            formatResult: tagResultList, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
            formatSelection: tagResultSelectionName,  // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
            dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop" // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
        });
    </script>
```

I can type and choose a new tag(create new tag) but the problem is that when submitting the textbox will forward Id 0 to the server and there Is no way to know what the created tag was named.

So how do I get it to send the string instead of the id to the service? Or could there be a mixed mode like id for existing and string for created?

BestRegards

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term, // search term
                    page: page
                    ,newtag : 'created tag' //replace by var or jquery chain that'll return the string 
                }
```

it'll be send in the get array to _tagsurl  with index newtag

Comment: But you are only modifying the lookup function here? So when I type a new tag this function will run for every letter typed. If the enduser dont see the tag in the loaded list he can click on the tag that he have written and it will be added to the textbox(as Id o), this last part will not be known for the service until submitting. The problem is when submitting the form the viewModel will have a value like 0, 2, 7 where 0 is a new tag that we dont know the name of.